# How to deal with socket.io being undefined in app.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

My express app logic is separated into a separate file from the instantiation of the express server, so I'm having issues with accessing socket.io within this app file. Should I just move the socket.io implementation into index.js or is it possible to keep that logic in app.js?

index.js

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const config = require('./utils/config');
const logger = require('./utils/logger');

app.set('socketio', io);

server.listen(config.PORT, () => {
  logger.info(`Listening on port ${config.PORT}`);
});
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./utils/config');
const middleware = require('./utils/middleware');

const app = express();

app.use(middleware.requestLogger);

const io = app.get('socketio');

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      io.emit('test', { test: 'test' });
});

app.use(middleware.errorHandler);


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a load order problem.  You are loading `app.js` into `index.js` BEFORE you create and set `io` as an app property.  So, when `app.js` tries to use the `io` property, it hasn't yet been set.

The way you have things split between the files, you've created a circular dependency.  You can't create `io` until you've created the server, but you can't create the server until you have the `app` which is in `app.js`.  So, you can't create `io` before you load `app.js`.

There are lots of ways around this.  I find it kind of weird that you're creating the `server` in one file and the `app` object in another file since the two are fully required to make an operational server.  So, I'd rearrange how those things are done like this:

```
// index.js
const http = require('http');
const app = require('express')();

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.set('socketio', io);

require('./app.js')(app);

const config = require('./utils/config');
const logger = require('./utils/logger');


server.listen(config.PORT, () => {
  logger.info(`Listening on port ${config.PORT}`);
});
```

And, then modify app.js like this:

```
const config = require('./utils/config');
const middleware = require('./utils/middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(middleware.requestLogger);

    const io = app.get('socketio');

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        io.emit('test', { test: 'test' });
    });

    app.use(middleware.errorHandler);
}
```

There are 100 other ways to organize the code to fix this.  Exporting a function that you can call and passing that function one or more arguments is one way to help control the timing of these circular dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I rearranged as you suggested and that it took care of the issue, I figured it was an issue with the order but wasn't sure how to tackle it. Thanks again!